# Django - DRF Delete/Retrieve/Patch Returns 404 { detail: "Not found" }

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-queryset

After intensive debugging for about 4-5 hours. 
I give up trying to find what's causing this, probably really simple, bug.
Tried this with Update and Patch/Put Mixins, and didn't work as well.
It is 100% because of the queryset, but I can't find the problem?
Tried using .get() and everything else I could think of.

My View is pretty straightforward:

```
class RemoveModel3D(generics.DestroyAPIView):

    serializer_class = Model3DSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        user_pk = self.kwargs["pk"]
        return Model3D.objects.filter(owners__in=[user_pk])
```

P.S. That queryset is working perfectly fine with ListModelMixin. I read that List is for collections and Retrieve/Destroy/Update is for single model instance, but How do I get the queryset to be a single model instance? That I could not find anywhere

EDIT: Adding serializer and model snippets related to the issue

Serializers:

```
class Model3DSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    User = get_user_model()

    commits = CommitSerializer(many=True, required=False, read_only=True)
    favorited_by = UserSerializer(many=True, required=False, read_only=True)

    date_uploaded = serializers.DateTimeField(read_only=True)
    owners = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Model3D
        fields = (
            'id',
            'title',
            'owners',
            'description',
            'date_uploaded',
            'favorited_by',
            'commits'
        )
```

Model:

```
class Model3D(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    # Many models many owners, seems reasonable to me
    owners = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='owners')
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    date_uploaded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    # Many models many people who like them.
    favorited_by = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='favorited_by')
```

Views:

```
class ListAllModels3D(generics.ListAPIView):

    serializer_class = Model3DSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Model3D.objects.all()
        model_id = self.request.query_params.get('id', None)

        if model_id is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(pk=model_id)

        return queryset

class RemoveModel3D(generics.DestroyAPIView):

    serializer_class = Model3DSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Model3D.objects.all()
        model_id = self.request.query_params.get('id', None)

        if model_id is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(pk=model_id)

        return queryset


class Models3D( mixins.ListModelMixin,
            mixins.CreateModelMixin,
            generics.GenericAPIView,
        ):

    serializer_class = Model3DSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        user_pk = self.kwargs["pk"]
        return Model3D.objects.filter(owners__in=[user_pk])

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        # FIXME: this is a bad way to set the value, but ...
        user_id = self.kwargs["pk"]
        serializer.validated_data['owners'] = [user_id]

        serializer.save()
```

Comment: You class definitions are not indented properly. Please correct the code in the question so it is valid python syntax.

Comment: Representing m2m relations in nested enpoints can lead to very deeply nested and unwieldy apis. It's cleaner to use query filtering. `/api/v1/model3d/?owner=20`.

Comment: Are you sure `self.kwargs["pk"]` is the user pk in the detail, delete and patch views? The default is to use `{pk}` for the serializer_class. If you want nested routes, there are plugins available for that. https://chibisov.github.io/drf-extensions/docs/#nested-routes or https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers

Comment: yes I am sure the query in get_queryset is returning exactly what I want. It's just that .destroy .update .partitial_update methods don't like it, and return 404. .list method works perfectly, probably because the queryset is a collection/array, not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `lookup_url_kwarg` for a GenericApiView is `pk`. But you are using that to filter `User`, so you will use same pk value when querying for Owner and Model3D.

The result is similar to this pseudocode, which results in a 404 response unless the user and the model3d has the same pk.

```
kwargs = {'pk': 20} 
try:
   Model3D.objects.get(owners__in=[kwargs['pk']], pk=kwargs['pk'])
except ObjectNotFound:
   raise Http404Exception('Not found')
```

To solve this, either use a plugin with support for nested api routes. Or you could override the viewset `get_object` method, which is where the 404 is raised.

```
def get_object(self):
    queryset = self.get_queryset()
    pk = self.request.query_params.get('id', None)
    obj = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
    self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
    return obj
```

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#get_objectself

The `get_object` method is used by `retrieve()` (GET) `update()` PATCH/PUT and `destroy()` (DELETE) and the default is to use `self.kwargs['pk']` as lookup value.

Comment: You are golden!! Thanks so much!